# RxJava split list into partition

Tags: java, android, rx-java

how to create chunked lists of a big list

window:

```
Observable.just(mutableListOf(1,2,3,4,5,6))
                .window(2)
                .flatMap { chunk -> chunk }
                .map { chunk -> println("This is a chunk of 2 numbers -> ${chunk}") }
                .subscribe()
```

result `This is a chunk of 2 numbers -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

why? i mean, why not printing 3 times (3 lists containing 2 numbers each)

and for the buffer

```
Observable.just(mutableListOf(1,2,3,4,5,6))
                .buffer(2)
                .flatMap { chunk -> Observable.just(chunk) }
                .map { chunk -> println("This is a chunk of 2 numbers -> ${chunk}") }
                .subscribe()
```

the result of buffer -> `This is a chunk of 2 numbers -> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]`

this one almost did except the part of creating more lists for group of 2 numbers :O =(

some light?

Comment: at this time i solved it using kotlin chunked

Answer (score 0):

`Observable.just` gives you a stream of one element (the list). You should use `Observable.from`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with ***Rxjava2 Buffer***

- **Buffer -> periodically gather items emitted by an Observable into bundles and emit these bundles rather than emitting the items one at a time**

Here is the code to get it.

```
Observable.fromIterable(mutableListOf(1,2,3,4,5,6))
        .buffer(2, 2) 
        // First param: 2 means,  it takes max of 2 from its start index and create list 
        // seconds param 2 means, it jumps two step every time
        .map { chunk -> println("This is a chunk of 2 numbers -> ${chunk}") }
        .subscribe()
```

On the execution of the above code, it gives 3 lists. Each list contains 2 items in it.

> This is a chunk of 2 numbers -> {1, 2}
>
> This is a chunk of 2 numbers -> {3, 4}
>
> This is a chunk of 2 numbers -> {5, 6}